# Collapsibles/accordion in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using the following code for nested collapsible:

```
<div id= "accordion" data-role="collapsible" data-position="inline">
    <h2>
        <div class='ui-grid-a'>
            <div class='ui-block-a'>
                <?php echo $mydate ?>
            </div>
            <div class='ui-block-b'>
                <img align='right' src="/img/arrow.png"></img>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </h2>
        <?php foreach ($result as $id=>$res): ?>
            <p>
                <div id="accordion1" data-role="collapsible" data-position="inline">
                <h3>
                    <div class='ui-grid-a'>
                        <div class='ui-block-a'>
                            <?php echo $id; ?>
                        </div> 

                    </div>
                </h3>
                    <p> 
                        <?php foreach ($res as $r){
                         print_r($r['ID']); echo '<br>'; } ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </p>

        <?php endforeach; ?> 


    </div>
```

[image: overlapped collapsibles]

As you can see that the collapsibles are overlapped. 01-mar-2012 is one collapsible and department is another collapsible. Cold storage are the values for department collapsible.  Can anyone tell me what to do so that the values and other collapsibles are not overlapped (coldstorage is overlapped with 25 feb 2012)?

Thanks in anticipation.

BasicGem

Comment: You shouldn't be wrapping any p tags around all that content, especially not headings and other p tags. I'd concentrate on sorting that first.

Comment: Heading and content tags is how the accordion and collapsibles work in jquery :) - BG

Comment: This demo: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ doesn't. It's more like this:
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">Title of heading</a></h3>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Title of heading</a></h3>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Title of heading</a></h3>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you stylesheet

```
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Then just after you last `</p>` add this line `<div class="clearfix></div>`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Jon,
Thanks a lot for the reply. However, this does not work :( 

Regards,

Comment: I solved it by myself. I used an accordion instead of a collapsible and fiddled around and it worked. This is where i found help.

http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/638/Super-simple-Multi-level-accordion-jQuery-plugin